# Retrieve firebase collection based on uid in React.js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I must've read like 50-100 articles regarding this topic. Still I can't seem to solve it, nor understand it.

Within my Firestore database, I have a collection called **"documents"**. Each document has their own **"uid"**-field. I am trying to retrieve the collection based on the uid of the user that's signed in.

I have come to the conclusion that my application isn't getting the user before the "unSubscribe" function runs. Probably since my user is **null** (which it initially is) when the useEffect first runs. But what should I do to make the function to wait for the user to become anything else than null? If that's the logic I should use.

***PS. Also it seems like the where function isn't being used. How come?***

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth'
import { db, auth } from '../firebase/config'
import { collection, onSnapshot, query, where } from 'firebase/firestore'

import AddDocument from './AddDocument'
import Document from './Document'

const DocumentList = ({ title }) => {

    const [user, setUser] = useState()
    const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([])

    console.log(user)

    useEffect(() => {

      onAuthStateChanged(auth, currentUser => {
        setUser(currentUser)
      })

      const documentCollection = collection(db, 'documents').where('uid', '==', user.uid)

      const unSubscribe = onSnapshot(documentCollection, (snapshot) => {
        let results = []
        snapshot.docs.forEach(document => {
            results.push({...document.data(), id: document.id})
        })
        setDocuments(results)
      })

      return () => unSubscribe()

    }, [user])

    return (
        <div className="mt-16">
            <h5 className="text-gray-500">{title}</h5>
            <div className="grid grid-cols-8 mt-4">
                {documents && documents.map((props) => (
                    <Document key={props.id} {...props} />
                ))}
                <AddDocument />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DocumentList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is that all code that needs the current user should be *inside* the `onAuthStateChanged` callback, as otherwise `user` won't have the correct value yet. So:

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, currentUser => {
  setUser(currentUser)
  const documentCollection = collection(db, 'documents').where('uid', '==', currentUser.uid)
                                                                          //  
  const unSubscribe = onSnapshot(documentCollection, (snapshot) => {
    let results = []
    snapshot.docs.forEach(document => {
      results.push({...document.data(), id: document.id})
    })
    setDocuments(results)
  })
})
//return () => unSubscribe() //  This will also have to change
```